# Passing data to createApp (vue)

Tags: vuejs3

Using Webpack, I have this code:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/ItemSearch/ItemSearch.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#search-app')
```

On my website, I have a page for the search app that contains the `<div id="search-app" />` to mount the root of the application to.

What I would like to know is, whether it's possible to somehow insert (preferably) **some** of the data from the page that includes the javascript file? There are a few things items I would like to include from the database, such as settings and search categories, and I'd like to avoid making an AJAX request for them if it can be helped.

Can it be helped or is there some way I can include this data inline at load time?

With Webpack, I don't quite understand how I can get access to App from the page that loads the javascript file, so that I can modify `data` before somehow passing it in to `createApp()`, or if it's even possible. Can I use `import` statements on a page that's loaded by the browser, or is this stictly a Webpack only (or similar) feature?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `createApp`'s second parameter to pass props.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/ItemSearch/ItemSearch.vue'
    
createApp(App, {myProp: "value"}).mount('#search-app')
```

[docs](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#createapp)

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get Vue 3 working correctly for my app, so I had to default back to Vue 2. Thanks for your response.

Comment: How can this data be accessed in `ItemSearch.vue` file?

Comment: @jakubiszon they the values passed through `rootProps` parameter are the props